# How to pass text after video processing using WebRTC?

Tags: python, webrtc, aiohttp, aiortc

My task is to get the video stream from the client's webcam, analyze it and return the result as a string. Reading the documentation on aiortc and looking at their examples on [git](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/main/examples/server), I could only do this option:

```
async def offer(request):
    params = await request.json()
    offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])

    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    pcs.add(pc)

    await server(pc, offer)

    return web.Response(
        content_type="application/json",
        text=json.dumps(
            {"sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp, "type": pc.localDescription.type}
        ),
    )

pcs = set()

async def server(pc, offer):
    @pc.on("connectionstatechange")
    async def on_connectionstatechange():
        print("Connection state is %s" % pc.connectionState)
        if pc.connectionState == "failed":
            await pc.close()
            pcs.discard(pc)

    @pc.on("track")
    def on_track(track):
        print("======= received track: ", track)
        if track.kind == "video":
            global new_video_track
            new_video_track = Sign(track)
            pc.addTrack(new_video_track)

    @pc.on("datachannel")
    def on_datachannel(channel):
        global new_video_track
        new_video_track.channel = channel
        print("mounted channel")

        @channel.on("message")
        async def on_message(message):
            if isinstance(message, str):
                data = message.encode("utf-8")
            else:
                data = message
            print("receive data: ", data)

    await pc.setRemoteDescription(offer)
    answer = await pc.createAnswer()
    await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)


async def on_shutdown(app):
    # close peer connections
    coros = [pc.close() for pc in pcs]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    pcs.clear()

class Sign(VideoStreamTrack):
    kind = "video"

    def __init__(self, track):
        super().__init__()
        self.track = track
        self.channel = None

    async def recv(self):
        frame = await self.track.recv()
        
        # getting the result I need

        if self.channel and self.sentence:
                self.channel.send(json.dumps({'word': self.sentence}))
        return frame
```

But this result is not satisfactory, because I need to return the frame. How to make it so that only my word is returned.

Here's the client.js

```
var pc = null;
var localVideo = document.querySelector("video#localVideo");
var serverVideo = document.querySelector("video#serverVideo");

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {

    height: 1080,
    width: 1920,

    frameRate: {
      max: 10
    }   
}

}).then(stream => {
  localVideo.srcObject = stream;
  localVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    localVideo.play();
  });
});

function negotiate () {
  return pc.createOffer().then(function (offer) {
    return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
  }).then(function () {
    // wait for ICE gathering to complete
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
        resolve();
      } else {
        function checkState () {
          if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
            pc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
            resolve();
          }
        }
        pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
      }
    });
  }).then(function () {
    var offer = pc.localDescription;
    return fetch('/offer', {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sdp: offer.sdp,
        type: offer.type,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST'
    });
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function (answer) {
    return pc.setRemoteDescription(answer);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    alert(e);
  });
}

function start () {
  var config = {
    sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan',
    iceServers: [{ urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'] }]
  };

  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

  localVideo.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
    pc.addTrack(track);
  });
  pc.addEventListener('track', function (evt) {
    console.log("receive server video");
    if (evt.track.kind == 'video') {
      serverVideo.srcObject = evt.streams[0];
    }
  });
  ch = pc.createDataChannel("chat", {
    ordered: false,
    maxRetransmits: 0,
  });
  ch.addEventListener("message", function (evt) {
    console.log(Date.now() - JSON.parse(evt.data).now);
  });

  document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
  negotiate();
  document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'inline-block';
}



function stop () {
  document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';
  setTimeout(function () {
    pc.close();
  }, 500);
}
```

Thank you in advance and forgive the large chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jinja template. You can send only variable values.
This is an example of jinja template https://aiohttp-jinja2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/